# Ubuntu 22.04 software installer crashes

Tags: software-installation

new installation Ubuntu 22.04 today, trying to install software but opens and closes immediately. Have uninstalled and re-installed as suggested but no change, any advise please?

Comment: please [edit] your question to detail what steps/commands you took and from what source of reference to uninstall and re-install. As your question curentl stands, it is difficult to respond.

Comment: Check your logs, you are probably missing a library.

Comment: Snapcraft, which the Software Center uses in the background, is experiencing intermittent outages today due to a firewall issue on their part. It should be back up-and-running soon (hopefully).